# Remove filter from child element HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, css-selectors, svg-filters

I am working on a project and and am having an issue trying to remove a filter from a child element. I created a small code snippet of the issue I am running into.

Does anyone have any recommendations that I may try?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
    <body>
        <div class="container filter">
            <div class="nofilter">
                <p>hello</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nofilter">
                <p>hello</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nofilter">
                <p>hello</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nofilter">
                <p>hello</p>
            </div>
        </div>  
            
        <svg> 
            <defs>
            <filter id="goo">
                <fegaussianblur in="sourcegraphic"
                stddeviation="10"/>
                <fecolormatrix in="name" mode="matrix"
                               values ="1 0 0 0 0
                                        0 1 0 0 0
                                        0 0 1 0 0
                                        0 0 0 30 -15" />
                <feblend in="sourcegraphic" />          
            </filter>
            </defs>
        </svg>
        
    </body>
```

`CSS`

```
 body {height: 100%;
    width: 100%;}
    
    .container, .filter {width: 50%;
    height: 200%;
    background-color: green;
    filter: url(#goo);
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
    }
    
    .nofilter 
    {width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto auto;
    background-color: aqua;;
    filter: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;}
```

Comment: reparent the child divs so they don't have a filtered parent. Or alternatively filter specific children only and not the parent.

Comment: @RobertLongson what do you mean when you say  "Reparent" ?